# psycopg2 execute_values with list of class objects

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have a class `Person` with `id`, `fname`, and `lname`. My program will have a large list of `Person` objects, which I would like to insert into my `PostgreSQL` database.

I would like to do this through `psycopg2.execute_values` method, which requires `__getitem__` to be defined for my class.

`__getitem__` is currently returning `tuple(id, fname, lname)`, which results in `pscopg2.execute_values` trying to execute: `insert into persons(id, fname, lname) values ((1, 'test1', 'test1'))...`

```
import psycopg2.extras


class Person:
    def __init__(self, id, fname, lname):
        self.id = id
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname

    def __len__(self):
        return 1

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.id, self.fname, self.lname


dsn = "user=my_user host=localhost port=5432 dbname=my_db"
query = "insert into persons(id, fname, lname) values %s"

p1 = Person(1, 'test1', 'test1')
p2 = Person(2, 'test2', 'test2')

records = list()
records.append(p1)
records.append(p2)
with psycopg2.connect(dsn=dsn) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cursor, query, records, template=None, page_size=1000)

psycopg2.ProgrammingError: INSERT has more target columns than expressions
LINE 1: insert into persons(id, fname, lname) values ((1, 'test1', 'test1'))...
                                ^
HINT:  The insertion source is a row expression containing the same number of columns expected by the INSERT. Did you accidentally use extra parentheses?
```

Using a `namedtuple` works:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import psycopg2.extras


Person = namedtuple('Person', ['id', 'fname', 'lname'])

dsn = "user=my_user host=localhost port=5432 dbname=my_db"
query = "insert into persons(id, fname, lname) values %s"

p1 = Person(1, 'test1', 'test1')
p2 = Person(2, 'test2', 'test2')

records = list()
records.append(p1)
records.append(p2)

with psycopg2.connect(dsn=dsn) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cursor, query, records, template=None, page_size=1000)
```

However, I want to implement a different `__eq__` and `__hash__` implementation. If there is a way to override these methods for a `namedtuple` then I'm willing to go with that approach.

Otherwise how can I modify `__getitem__` to return `id`, `fname`, and `lname` separately so that the query becomes:

```
insert into persons(id, fname, lname) values (1, 'test1', 'test1')...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining `__conform__` seems to do the trick: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0246/

```
import psycopg2.extras
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs, ISQLQuote


class Person:
    def __init__(self, id, fname, lname):
        self.id = id
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname

    def __len__(self):
        return 1

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self

    def __conform__(self, protocol):
        if protocol is ISQLQuote:
            return AsIs("{id}, '{fname}', '{lname}'".format(id=self.id, fname=self.fname, lname=self.lname))

        return None


dsn = "user=my_user host=localhost port=5432 dbname=my_db"
query = "insert into persons(id, fname, lname) values %s"

p1 = Person(1, 'test1', 'test1')
p2 = Person(2, 'test2', 'test2')

records = list()
records.append(p1)
records.append(p2)

with psycopg2.connect(dsn=dsn) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cursor, query, records, template=None, page_size=1000)
```

Unsure if this is the recommended method, so I will keep this open in hopes that someone chimes in.

Comment: This is potentially open to SQL injection. https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#adapting-new-python-types-to-sql-syntax shows an example of creating an adapter for a class and they call `adapt(x).getquoted()` on all values before passing them to `AsIs`. I will post an answer when I have time to work on this my self.